# How to change a specific value range when multiple keys are present?

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I have this string:

```
Avarage Age=12 <-> 25 ; Pension Age=60 <-> 72; Nationality=[UK, USA, German, France]
```

The ultimate goal is to apply a regex to change the range of a specified field e.g.: from `'Age=12 <-> 25'` to `'Age=10 <-> 30'`.

How can I do this?

I've tried and I have two questions:

(1) If I made a regex to search for (e.g.:): `/d+<->d+/ig` it'll return both Age and Pension Age. Can I make a regex that searches for a KEY=range **but** just return the range (returns means that I can replace with another range)?

(2) With this (just returning what I need: Age):

```
NSString *pattern = @"Age=\d+<->\d+";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string
                                                           options:0
                                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                                                      withTemplate:@"**??????**"];
```

How can I change the integers 12 and 25 from *withTemplate*?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything fancy. Just include the `Age=` in the value used for `withTemplate:`.

```
NSString *pattern = @"Age=\d+<->\d+";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string
                                                           options:0
                                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                                                      withTemplate:@"Age=10 <-> 30"];
```

Comment: and if I want to pass 10 and 30 as parameters to "withTemplate"?

Comment: Then use a string format to build the template: `NSString *template = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Age=%d <-> %d", lowerNum, upperNum];`.